# CollectionFS and CFS-S3 Meteor small help needed

Tags: javascript, meteor, dom-events

I created a simple site to handle uploads with collectionFS, http://uploadapp.meteor.com/, when I click on upload it uploads the file to my AS3 bucket but if I click on the uploaded image in the site and copy url it gives me a local url example:

http://uploadapp.meteor.com/cfs/files/videos/tn877RSLTC2S6SnwG/download%20(1).jpeg?token=eyJhdXRoVG9rZW4iOiJHYkpZVkZ4V0dOLUlCQmJPbzdrdUxxS3VuQ3FDWDFBOUtSNzBBV1p3X0t3In0%3D

this means that the image is showing uploading to the mongodb and to as3?

how can I make it show  and upload only and directly from AS3? (the images are stored to the as3 bucket so the upload is working)

The event handler for the upload form is :

```
Template.hello.events({
    'change .fileInput':function(evt,tmpl){
      FS.Utility.eachFile(event,function(file){
        var fileObj = new FS.File(file);
        Videos.insert(fileObj),function(err){
          console.log(err);
        }
      })
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

The URL is simply a proxy to the actual image. The reason it's like this is it needs to sign the url to be displayed.

It's not actually on your mongodb its only on S3.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out too when I deleted the image and got deleteed from the amazon account too.